# A GetModuleHandle implementation

Tags: winapi, dll-injection, loaderlock

I need to do it this way because I am in `DllMain()` therefore, **loader lock** is held. I've read that `GetModuleHandle()` [also uses the loader lock [page #6]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx)  which would result in deadlock.

How could GetModuleHandle() implemented? Some code would be a plus.

**Update**: Since I am using `SetWindowsHookEx` on WinXP only. Just going to take advice in the comments, go the easy way, and use GetModuleHandle() the first time the callback gets called.

Comment: Can't you just export an `Init` function that will do all the "dangerous" stuff, and call it from the outside after `DllMain` was completed? You're looking for trouble if you're doing complicated things in `DllMain`.

Comment: @eran, no not with my mode of API injection. It is legacy 'API hooking' code, to support WinXP.

Comment: Try it the easy way before trying it the hard way. Just add a few lines of code to the target program to have it load your DLL if a special debugging switch is passed, say.

Comment: Windows XP SP2 adds ASLR, otherwise I could read 0x7ffdf000 which used to be the PEB, and walk that to get the loaded module's base address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `GetModuleHandle` from `DllMain`. It doesn't load any libraries and doesn't increment module reference count. Other story is with `LoadLibrary`. Never call it from `DllMain`.

Comment: A Microsoft document implies that `GetModuleHandle()` **can** hold a loader lock. (Page 6) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx

Comment: It is ok as long as you stay in the dllmain thread. Loader lock is reenterable.

Comment: It does increment the reference count, the reason the lock must acquired.  Review GetModuleHandleEx() and the GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT
 option.

Comment: GetModuleHandleEx does but GetModuleHandle doesn't.